# Check if the email already exists in Firebase Auth unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, authentication, firebase-authentication

I want to check if the email already exists in firebase authentication before the user clicks on sign up button if there is a way.

I tried to write one with the login firebase method but it doesn't work correctly because I need the password to check.

if there is a method to check only the mail.

I am so thankful to hear your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`FetchProvidersForEmailAsync`  method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/firebase-auth#fetchprovidersforemailasync), which returns a list of providers for the given email address.

It returns a list of providers, instead of just true/false, so that you can show a UI for each of the providers that the user can use to sign in to their account.